# Transparent or Opaque backgrounds with an image in css

Tags: css

I have a site that uses images for buttons, and I have a few images with some white space in the background, they are rounded rectangle buttons like the app store icon.  They look good when compared to a background with white space, but when I use anything other than white, the little white space shows up and it looks terrible.  Is there any sort of way that I can set the transparency color so that white space will disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make them PNGs or GIFs.  PNGs support transparency and are the most common, as they also support higher quality images.

You can use a free photo editing program like GIMP to 'select' the white and delete it out.

http://www.gimp.org/

Photoshop is also a popular tool.

Comment: Important to note here, is that PNG (24-bit anyways) is not supported in IE6, and poorly in IE7/8. Also, PNG doesn't "just produce better quality", it does so because of Alpha-channels, whereas the transparency in a .gif is just 1 of the 256 colors it can display. Which means that a pixel in a .gif is either transparent, or completely opaque. This is not the case in PNG24 where there's a scale of transparency on each pixel.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus what do you mean with 'poorly in IE7/8'?

Comment: @ptriek Poor/Buggy implementation, that's all. PNG's also render somewhat slower in IE7 than in IE9, FF, Opera, Chrome or Safari, for instance.